# how to pick maximum date from a group of dates coming through source,other than high date?

Tags: informatica

I have around 7 fields coming from source. I need to pick the highest date of them all in an informatica expression. I may also get a default high date (12/31/9999) in any fields, but if that date shows up in any of the fields , then that has to be skipped in comparison.

e.g, if my source fields have data - 1/1/2001 , 1/2/2002, 2/2,2003, 12/31/999.

Then my expression output has to be 2/2/2003.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you create an expression and having an issue? OR Are you simply expecting us to create the expression and spoon feed you?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on SQ level ( custom sql query ) or Informatica level : 
https://forgetcode.com/informatica/1472-greatest-find-greatest-value

Step 1:

Define check for each field ( or do it inline )

```
DATE_1_CHECKED =  IIF( DATE_1 = TO_DATE('9999.. ', 'YYYY-' ), NULL, DATE_1)
```

Step 2:

```
GREATEST(DATE_1, DATE_2, DATE_3 )
```

ps. I'm not sure about casting function TO_DATE, please read doc.

ps. If You want to cut precission of date/time in informatica, please use trim(DATE_1, 'DD') to get date with HH24:MM:SS zero filled.

Answer (score 1):

Create additional port that will discard the default, like

```
agg_Date = IIF(in_Date = '12/31/9999', NULL, in_Date)
```

Now use `agg_Date` in Aggregator Transformation to calculate MAX.

Answer (score 0):

write an IIF to compare the date values using < , > and output the greatest one and !=12/31/999